# Firebase cloud message not follow the implementation in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Good afternoon 
anyone knows why, does the Firebase cloud message not follow the implementation of the extended class when the application is in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, my server was sending the message as notification and there are two types of FCM
NotificationMessages: Sending a payload with this type of message triggers onMessageReceived () only when your application is in the foreground.
DateMessages: Send a payload with only this type of specific message triggers, onMessageReceived () regardless of whether your application is in the foreground / background.